# Get title attribute with jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have a problem with parsing a website. 
The website contains a phrase like this:

```jsp
<td class="school">
<abbr title data-original-title="Highschool">...</abbr>
</td>
```

How can I get the title (Highschool)?
I'm programming with jsoup and java.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try reading [jsoup cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html).

First you should get *abbr* element, and then its *data-original-title* attribute:

```
Element abbrElement = doc.select("abbr").first();
String originalTitle = abbrElement.attr("data-original-title");
```

Of course you should make sure that you select right *abbr* element. Above code will select the first one appearing in the document.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively easy using jsoup's DOM methods or selection on a parsed document.  Check out these links for reference:

[DOM navigation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation)

[Extracting attributes](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

```
//assuming that the class "school" contains the tag for the title
Elements titles = doc.getElementsByClass("school").getElementsByTag("abbr");
for (Element t: titles) {
   String title= t.attr("data-original-title");
   //do something with the title
}
```